# I want to retrieve current logged in user data from firestore but it shows blank where I want to show my data

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the current logged in user from the google firestore database
and i saw this same problem in stackoverflow of a user and i used that same method but showing blank in place user details.

Please help me Thanks.

I am earlier using querysnapshot as it gives all the users.

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnW2Y.jpg)

the image for database is 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M2dQ.png)

The code is:

```
 public class UserProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
static final int GALLERY_INTENT = 2;
private static final String TAG = "UserProfile";
String UserId;

FirebaseAuth auth;
ImageButton Photo;
ImageView photoview;
TextView name, email, password, phone;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
    if(getSupportActionBar()!=null ){

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }


    DatabaseReference Database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    DatabaseReference DBRef = Database.child("users");
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    UserId = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        FirebaseFirestore mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    StorageReference mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    photoview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photoview);
    Photo = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Photoedit);
    name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.username);
    email = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.useremail);
    password = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.password1);
    phone = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userPhone);
      mFirestore.collection("users").document(UserId).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                  String Name = documentSnapshot.getString("Name");
                  String Email = documentSnapshot.getString("Email");
                  String Password = documentSnapshot.getString("Password");
                  String Phone = documentSnapshot.getString("Phone Number");

                  name.setText(Name);
                  email.setText(Email);
                  password.setText(Password);
                  phone.setText(Phone);
          }
});


    Photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectImage();
        }
    });

}

private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserProfile.this);

    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");

    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

            if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))

            {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);



                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            }

            else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))

            {

                Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT);



            }

            else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {

                dialog.dismiss();

            }

        }

    });

    builder.show();

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        photoview.setImageBitmap(photo);



    } else if (requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

        String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);

        c.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);

        String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);

        c.close();

        Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        Log.w("path of image ", picturePath + "");

        photoview.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);


    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        Intent i = new Intent(UserProfile.this,category.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

My database structure is

Ramiki(my app name) 
So here it is

```
Ramiki --> users(collection)--> SiQEIDaQJfUBqZBBt1eo(document uid)----> fields(Email, Name, Password, Phone Number).
```

Well sorry i am not able to give screenshort because i am not allowed by stack overflow 10 points needed.

And my code for writing data in firestore is

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextName;
private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextEmail;
private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextPassword;
private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextConfirmPassword;
private TextInputEditText textInputEditTextPhone;
private AppCompatButton appCompatButtonRegister;
private AppCompatTextView appCompatTextViewLoginLink;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private SignInButton btnSignIn;
private FirebaseFirestore mFirebaseFirestore;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

     mFirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
            .setPersistenceEnabled(true)
            .build();
    mFirebaseFirestore.setFirestoreSettings(settings);


    authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {


        }
    };


    btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    // Customizing G+ button
    btnSignIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    btnSignIn.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());


    appCompatTextViewLoginLink = (AppCompatTextView) findViewById(R.id.appCompatTextViewLoginLink);
    appCompatTextViewLoginLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, account.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

    //if the user is already logged in we will directly start the category activity
    if (SavesharedPreferences.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, category.class));
        finish();
        return;

    }


    findViewById(R.id.appCompatButtonRegister).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String Name = textInputEditTextName.getText().toString().trim();
            String Email = textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String Password = textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            String Phone_Number = textInputEditTextPhone.getText().toString().trim();
            String ConfirmPassword = textInputEditTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);




            // Create a new user with a first and last name
            Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
            user.put("Name", Name);
            user.put("Email", Email);
            user.put("Password", Password);
            user.put("Phone Number", Phone_Number);

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Name)) {
                textInputEditTextName.setError("Please enter name");
                textInputEditTextName.requestFocus();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Email)) {
                textInputEditTextEmail.setError("Please enter your email");
                textInputEditTextEmail.requestFocus();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            else if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(Email).matches()) {
                textInputEditTextEmail.setError("Email already exist");
                textInputEditTextEmail.requestFocus();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }


           else  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Password)) {
                textInputEditTextPassword.setError("Enter a password");
                textInputEditTextPassword.requestFocus();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            else if(Password.length() < 7){
                textInputEditTextPassword.setError("Paasword must be greater than 7 digits");
                textInputEditTextPassword.requestFocus();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            else if (!textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().equals(textInputEditTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString())) {
                textInputEditTextPassword.setError("Password Doesn't Match");
                textInputEditTextPassword.requestFocus();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            else {


     // Add a new document with a generated ID
                mFirebaseFirestore.collection("users")
                        .add(user)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {

                                registerUser();
                                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e);
                            }
                        });


            }
        }


    });



    initViews();




}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();

    switch (id) {

        case R.id.btn_sign_in:
            signIn();
            break;


    }
}

private void registerUser() {
    final String Name = textInputEditTextName.getText().toString().trim();
    final String Email = textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String Password = textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    final String Phone_Number = textInputEditTextPhone.getText().toString().trim();
    final String ConfirmPassword = textInputEditTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    //first we will do the validations

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Name)) {
        textInputEditTextName.setError("Please enter name");
        textInputEditTextName.requestFocus();
        return;

    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Email)) {
        textInputEditTextEmail.setError("Please enter your email");
        textInputEditTextEmail.requestFocus();
        return;

    }

    if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(Email).matches()) {
        textInputEditTextEmail.setError("Email already exist");
        textInputEditTextEmail.requestFocus();
        return;

    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Password)) {
        textInputEditTextPassword.setError("Enter a password");
        textInputEditTextPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
   }

   if(Password.length() < 7 ) {
       textInputEditTextPassword.setError("Paasword must be greater than 7 digits");
       textInputEditTextPassword.requestFocus();
       return;
   }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(ConfirmPassword)) {
        textInputEditTextPassword.setError("Password Doesn't Match");
        textInputEditTextPassword.requestFocus();
        return;

    }


    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //create user
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Register Successful " + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        sendEmailVerification();
                    }



                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    else if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Nothing Happens", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });



}

private void sendEmailVerification() {
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if(user != null){
        user.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Please Check Your Email For Verification",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, account.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}


private void initViews() {


    textInputEditTextName = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextName);
    textInputEditTextEmail = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextEmail);
    textInputEditTextPassword = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextPassword);
    textInputEditTextPhone = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextPhone);
    appCompatTextViewLoginLink = (AppCompatTextView) findViewById(R.id.appCompatTextViewLoginLink);
    textInputEditTextConfirmPassword = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextConfirmPassword);
    appCompatButtonRegister = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.appCompatButtonRegister);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "You Got an Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}



protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    auth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
            // ...
        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {

    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
}


}
```

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: I have edited my post to give database structure just like in cloud firestore.  In Brackets words are for details where they placed in database.

Comment: Please also share, how you are adding the users to the database.

Comment: @Alex I have updated the code for writing the data in firestore. i have used authentication(from email & password and google both), registering of user in firestore database. And i have also included the image of database above in details.

Answer (score 0):

This unique id `SiQEIDaQJfUBqZBBt1eo` is generated when you are adding the user as a `Map` or when you are using a call to `document()` method without passing an argument.

In order to solve this, there are two ways. One would be to create a model class (UserModel), then create an object of that class and in the end get the uid of the user once it authenticated and add the object to the database like this:

```
String Name = textInputEditTextName.getText().toString().trim();
String Email = textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
String Password = textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
String Phone_Number = textInputEditTextPhone.getText().toString().trim();
String ConfirmPassword = textInputEditTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString().trim();

UserModel userModel = new UserModel(Name, Email, Password, Phone_Number, ConfirmPassword);
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference usersRef = rootRef.collection("users");
usersRef.document(uid).set(userModel);
```

See, I have passed the `uid` as argument to the `document()` method.

The second approach would be to pass no argument to the `document()` method but to store that key into a variable like this:

```
String key = usersRef.document().getKey();
usersRef.document(key).set(userModel);
```

**Edit:**

There also another method, which I recommend you use it. Instead of using this line of code:

```
 mFirebaseFirestore.collection("users")
                    .add(user)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(/* ... */)
```

Use the following line of code:

```
 mFirebaseFirestore.collection("users")
                    .document(uid)
                    .set(user)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(/* ... */)
```

Remove the old data, add fresh one and your problem will be solved.

Comment: I am already using the model class which contain first 4 fields not including Confirm password

Comment: i am new to android, So not able to understand your answer much .     String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();    i have added this line  in my user profile and it gives nullpointer at the getUid();   used as line--- String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();                       Thanks for telling and give your time.

Comment: I have exaplained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** step by step, the entire authentication process using **[Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwgMWBhObDw&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=5)** and **[Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIRt9Ts0fRU&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=6)**. You should take a look.

Comment: Please also see my updated answer for an easier solution.

Comment: after changing my code to that you suggested in updated part i am getting error of     -------    addOnSuccessListener
(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener<? super java.lang.Void>)
in Task cannot be applied
to
(anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener<com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference>) .....                                                                        More Over i am getting NullPointer Exception  on getUid() when using this line UserId = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

Comment: I have used the OnSuccessListener<Void> also but the data is overwriiten on the existing one and i don't want that.

Comment: If the data is overwriiten, then just use instead of the `set` method, `update` method. Does it work now?

Comment: I am not having problem in adding the data to the firestore instead in retrieval i am having problems. So please tell me that. Thanks

Comment: That's right, you have problems with getting data because you have problems when setting data in the first place, which is incorrect. That's why you are having problems in retrieval. Have you tried my solution above?

Comment: You have to consider also that i am getting NullPointer Exception on getUid() when using this line UserId = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid(); .............    May be this line is giving problem.

Comment: Yes, that line is causing you problems and this is because you are setting the id in a wrong way. So you have problems when reading because you are setting it wrong.

Comment: I have used your update method also but it is also overwritting the data.

Comment: Really, have you tried my solution above, to use the uid when you add data? If not, try it, will solve your problem. Don't forget to delete the old data and add new one.